# Why does my raster layer disappear when changing colors?

Tags: qgis, raster, colormap

When I change the colors of a raster layer (EVI), the layer disappears. Here are my color settings: [image]

Comment: Without the raster's meta data, there is not enough information for a better answer than aldo's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your layer doesn't dissapear, only the values are out of range. Maybe pixel values of your layer are smaller than 2567 or bigger than 6749.

You have activated "Clip out of range values", deselect it and set automatically min/max value:

[image: printscreen]